# issue in setting marker on google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(address){ 

        var address = "{{ userprofile.work_street }},{{userprofile.work_suburb}},{{userprofile.work_postcode}},{{ userprofile.work_country }}";
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({               
        map: map,        
        position: results[0].geometry.location,  
           });
             $("#img-clck").hide();

             } 
           });  
         $('#refreshmap').on('click', address);        
       });
```

html:

```
<button type="button" id="refreshmap" class="map_buttons button_style">Refresh map</button>
```

Onload it is showing the marker on the specified address,if i press refresh button,the map gets refreshing,but after 4 or 5 times refreshing the marker gets disappeared.

Need help.

Comment: if you zoom out do you still find the marker elsewhere on the map?

Comment: Perhaps if you refresh it 4 or 5 times quickly, the value of status is no longer equal to "OK" (if you run into the rate limit or the quota), add an else to that "if" to display the status: `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {...} else alert(status);`

Comment: @pythonian29033,yes one more marker is set by me related to latitude and longitude.Same marker is nowhere in the screen

Comment: okay, try geocodezip's solution first,
 maybe you should pan the marker into the view?

Comment: nevermind, you're already doing that